# Classic asp file upload with jquery goodness?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

Is there a combination of Classic ASP file uploading and JQUery that you've used to make a clean and solid Classic ASP Upload/progress bar/ajax solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current favourite on the client side is [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which if you [disable chunking](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php)
works fine with classic ASP scripts, and the ASP side can be as simple or as complicated as you like.

The ASP page merely needs to receive a single file and process it however you want with whatever component or native solution you use for file uploads.

Answer (score 2):

File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&drop support, progress bars and preview images for jQuery. Supports cross-domain..

Classic ASP
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Classic-ASP